# Aggregate strings

Tags: google-sheets

Can Google Sheets queries aggregate strings?
I want to aggregate all locations for all years, so the following:

```
year     location
2013     Sudan
2014     Syria
2012     India
2014     Poland
2014     Great Britain
```

Should be transformed to:

```
year     locations
2012     India
2013     Sudan
2014     Syria, Poland, Great Britain
```

The problem is that `=QUERY(select year, sum(location) group by year)` does not work, neither does `=QUERY(select year, concatenate(location) group by year)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [aggregation functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en#aggregation-functions) available for `query` do not include concatenation of strings.

An alternative approach, illustrated by the following example:

```
+---+------+---------------+------+------------------------------+
|   |  A   |       B       |  C   |              D               |
+---+------+---------------+------+------------------------------+
| 1 | year | location      | year | locations                    |
| 2 | 2013 | Sudan         | 2012 | India                        |
| 3 | 2014 | Syria         | 2013 | Sudan                        |
| 4 | 2012 | India         | 2014 | Syria, Poland, Great Britain |
| 5 | 2014 | Poland        |      |                              |
| 6 | 2014 | Great Britain |      |                              |
+---+------+---------------+------+------------------------------+
```

C2 `=sort(unique(A2:A))`

returns sorted list without repetitions

D2 `=if(C2="", , join(", ", filter(B$2:B, A$2:A=C2)))`

picks the countries for the given year and joins them into a comma-separated string

The formula from D2 needs to be dragged/copied down the column; I couldn't come up with an `arrayformula` variant for it.

Answer (score 0):

I find that by replacing the separator `", "` with `char(10), =if(C2="", , join(char(10), filter(B$2:B, A$2:A=C2)))` the results are more easily read.